# 1980ish book, runestone, Tolkien elvish

Tags: story-identification

This is a somewhat forgettable (obviously) book I read in paperback, 1980 or 1981, in the US.

I believe it was set in the modern-day.  Someone discovers a runestone.  Somehow, (possibly involving blood sacrifice or ritual?) it opens a gateway to another world (or time?).  Some kind of killer (berserker? warrior of some time) may have come through.  That's about all I remember of the plot.

I think it was set in the British Isles, in "the moors", but I'm not 100% certain on that.

The most memorable thing about it is that the language used in this other world was Tolkien's Elvish (probably Sindarin).  I remember that I was able to translate it with just the bits I'd picked up from reading LoTR and The Silmarillion many times.  Even to my 14-15 year-old self, this didn't seem quite right to me - a bit of a ripoff of JRRT.

When I say 'runestone', it's possible it was some kind of system of standing stones like Stonehenge, but smaller.

Comment: The generic name for such a system is "stone henge" (wood henges also exist). (Incidentally, Stonehenge itself is not, strictly speaking, a henge.)

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like the Iron Tower trilogy by Dennis L McKiernan. I remember loving the series because of how much it looked and read like Tolkien. The hobbit analogs were the heroes, the other races had their own languages, and the magic token was a stone instead of a ring.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little bit further and add a some more content about why you think it could be the _Iron Tower trilogy_? What elements do they have in common? Thanks.

Comment: There's a very snarky review here (http://www.blackgate.com/2011/07/07/a-very-guilty-pleasure-dennis-mckiernan%E2%80%99s-the-iron-tower-trilogy/) that goes into a lot more detail about the similarities.

Comment: Definitely not those; I tried reading the first of the Iron Tower books a while back.  I'm pretty sure that the book I had in mind wasn't part of a series.